# Call a callback function in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, callback, drupal-7

I am currently trying to implement a callback function that will be call by my server at a specific url. I have this in my .module file :

```
function gestion_videos_menu() {
   $items = array();

   $items['callback'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'gestion_videos_callback',
    'file' => 'gestion_videos.callback.inc',
   );

 return $items;
 }
```

And the function gestion_videos_calback() in the above file. But I don't know if my implementation is correct, neither the url to reach my callback function (for example :`http://localhost:8888/drupal-7.22/search/node/#overlay=admin/config/media/gestionvideos/callback`)

Thank you for your help and advices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you now created, is a menu item listening on `http://localhost:8888/callback`.

If you want that your callback function is called on following url `http://localhost:8888/admin/config/media/gestionvideos/callback`, you need to define your menu item like this:

```
function gestion_videos_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/config/media/gestionvideos/callback'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'gestion_videos_callback',
        'file' => 'gestion_videos.callback.inc',
        'access callback' => true,
    );

    return $items;
 }
```

Notice the extra `access callback => true` value. This to define that each visitor has access to view the page. Don't forget to change this if you only want to allow certain roles by implementing [`hook_permissions`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) for custom permission or [`access arguments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for already existing permissions.